# drf swagger ui for json field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger-ui, django-swagger

Not able to show json array fields in swagger-ui of post body parameter.
I have django model with JsonField column, the column name is showing in swagger ui but not able to show inside json values. Request you to please give your suggestion.

```
#models
class Sample(models.Model):
    ApiUser = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ApiKey = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    create_array = models.JSONField()
    UserName = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    IPAddress = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

#serializers
class SampleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Sample
        fields = ('ApiUser','ApiKey','create_array','UserName','IPAddress')
```

for using above model and serializer I have following request body,

```
{
  "ApiUser": "string",
  "ApiKey": "string",
  "create_array": {},
  "UserName": "string",
  "IPAddress": "string"
}
```

but expected output is,

```
{
  "ApiUser": "string",
  "ApiKey": "string",
  "create_array": [{
  "name": "string",
  "id": "string", 
}],
  "UserName": "string",
  "IPAddress": "string"
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could extend the `serializers.JSONField` class ([docs](https://drf-swagger.readthedocs.io/en/latest/custom_spec.html#:%7E:text=Suppose%20you%20wanted%20to%20model%20an%20email%20using%20a%20JSONField%20to%20store%20the%20subject%20and%20body%20for%20performance%20reasons%3A)).
This would make your serializer look something like this:

```
class SampleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Sample
        fields = ('ApiUser','ApiKey','create_array','UserName','IPAddress')

    class createArrayJSONField(serializer.JSONField):
        class Meta:
            swagger_schema_fields = {
                "type": openapi.TYPE_OBJECT,
                "properties": {
                    "name": openapi.Schema(
                        type=openapi.TYPE_STRING,
                    ),
                    "id": openapi.Schema(
                        type=openapi.TYPE_STRING,
                    ),
                },
                "required": ["name", "id"],
             }

    create_array = createArrayJSONField()
```